# Google Analytics Javascript error

Tags: php, javascript, google-analytics

I have this page which used to return some other JavaScript errors, but it seems I fixed them since the system now complains differently :)

Here is the page:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/trailhead.php

And here is the JS error I am getting in the console:

> Unable to post message to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net. Recipient has origin http://www.comehike.com.

Also there is this error which is very cryptic:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-1884332214318974&output=html&h=90&slotname=6750679790&w=728&lmt=1307311140&flash=10.3.181&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comehike.com%2Foutdoors%2Fparks%2Ftrailhead.php&dt=1307285940734&bpp=5&shv=r20110527&jsv=r20110506&correlator=1307285940857&frm=4&adk=540157337&ga_vid=898509444.1299013740&ga_sid=1307285941&ga_hid=824315563&ga_fc=1&u_tz=-420&u_his=10&u_java=1&u_h=768&u_w=1366&u_ah=720&u_aw=1366&u_cd=32&u_nplug=14&u_nmime=51&biw=1345&bih=149&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comehike.com%2F&fu=0&ifi=1&dtd=291&xpc=egJ5ygbjaM&p=http%3A//www.comehike.com from frame with URL http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-1884332214318974&output=html&h=90&slotname=6750679790&w=728&lmt=1307311140&flash=10.3.181&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comehike.com%2Foutdoors%2Fparks%2Ftrailhead.php&dt=1307285940734&bpp=5&shv=r20110527&jsv=r20110506&correlator=1307285940857&frm=4&adk=540157337&ga_vid=898509444.1299013740&ga_sid=1307285941&ga_hid=824315563&ga_fc=1&u_tz=-420&u_his=10&u_java=1&u_h=768&u_w=1366&u_ah=720&u_aw=1366&u_cd=32&u_nplug=14&u_nmime=51&biw=1345&bih=149&ref=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comehike.com%2F&fu=0&ifi=1&dtd=291&xpc=egJ5ygbjaM&p=http%3A//www.comehike.com. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Any idea why they are happening and how to resolve them?

Here is how I try to return the XML in the AJAX:

```
    echo '<markers>';

    $str =
    <<<EOD

    <marker>
    trail_id=$trail_id
    trailhead_id=$trailhead_id
    park_id=$park_id
    editor_member_id=$editor_member_id
    trailhead_name=$trailhead_name
    trailhead_description=$trailhead_description
    parking=$parking
    cost_details=$cost_details
    parking_spots=$parking_spots
    is_free=$is_free
    wheelchair_accessible=$wheelchair_accessible
    bathrooms_nearby=$bathrooms_nearby
    lat=$lat
    lng=$lng

    </marker>
    EOD;

    echo $str;

// End XML file
echo '</markers>';
```

Comment: havent seen the error on your page

Comment: Are you trying to return xml via ajax from a domain different than the requesting page? I don't believe that's allowed by browsers.

Comment: @jen - no it is all within one domain.

Comment: Then it looks like they are bugs in the ads from google. Try taking your google ads off the page for testing. Then run the page and see if the errors still appear.

Comment: Is there a way to see the xml that is outputed?

Comment: When is it generated? You should be able to see it in the console of Firebug or Chrome.

Comment: Try: `var xmlDoc = request.responseXML; console.log(xmlDoc);` Then check the console in Firebug or Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error most likely is a side effect of something else going on on the page. Specifically something with the google maps API. The error Firefox throws is `Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "An invalid or illegal string was specified"  code: "12" nsresult: "0x8053000c (NS_ERROR_DOM_SYNTAX_ERR)"  location: "http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/5/5/main.js Line: 93"]`. I would try and remove everything Google Maps related from the page and see if the page loads without errors. Also I would try and create another blank page and copy everything Google Maps related from this page the way it is there and see if just Google Maps code runs without errors. That would show me that: 1) either the code that works with the map is doing something funky, or 2) The google maps code is conflicting with something else on the page.

P.S. i suspect the culprit is initializeTrailheads() method. Try removing it from onload and see what happens.

Comment: @Dimitri I took out the calls to all js, and now getting this error: Unable to post message to http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net. Recipient has origin http://www.comehike.com. - any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: do you have google adwords code on the page? If so, remove it also

Comment: @Dmitri nope, dont have adwords.  And removed the google adsense as well, but still getting the error

Comment: When you say you're getting errors, where are you getting them? I checked the page both in Firefox and IE and didn't get any (javascript) errors.

Comment: Actually in the end, deconstructing it and putting it back together worked :) - thank you!